# What does $o_n(1)$ mean?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, notation

I'm trying to read the following [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.06554), and in the abstract they write:
Let $\xi$ be a non-constant real-valued random variable with finite support, and let $M_n(\xi)$ denote a $n\times n$ random matrix with entries that are independent copies of $\xi$. For $\xi$ which is not uniform on its support, we show that:
$Pr[M_n(\xi) \text{ is singular}] = Pr[\text{zero row or column}]+ (1+o_n(1))Pr[\text{two equal (up to sign) rows or columns}]$.

What does $o_n(1)$ mean here?

Comment: It is hard to answer without any context…

Comment: My guess is that they mean $o(1)$ in the normal sense ([Landau notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations)), but since they are working with several variables, they add $n$ as subscript to mean "as $n$ goes to infinity".

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra but here we only have 1 variable n

Comment: @L.breitman Actually, there is also the variable $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, this $o_n(1)$ is meant as the standard “little o” notation (when $v_n$ takes non-zero values, $u_n = o(v_n)$ means $\frac{u_n}{v_n} → 0$), except that because several variables are involved ($n$, $ξ$, $p$), they added the $n$ subscript to clarify that the limit is as $n$ goes to infinity, for fixed values of the other variables. A perhaps more standard notation for what they write as $$x = o_n(y)$$ would be $$x \underset{n→+∞}{=} o(y)$$

Comment: This is consistent with the definition of $O_\alpha, \Omega_\alpha, \Theta_\alpha$ in the "Notation" section of the paper, although strangely they omit defining $o_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Given functions $f(n)$ and $G(n)$, from $[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)  $ we can define

| Operands | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| $f(n) = O_n(G(n))$ | $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf \frac{G(n)}{f(n)} > 0$ |
| $f(n) = o_n(G(n))$ | $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{G(n)}{f(n)} = 0$ |
| $f(n) = \Theta_n(G(n))$ | $f(n) = O(G(n)) \;\&\; G(n) = O(f(n))$ |
| $f(n) \sim_{n} G(n)$ | $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{G(n)}{f(n)} = 1$ |

Comment: The first one is incorrect.  E.g. $1 + \sin(n) = O(1)$ but $\lim 1/(1 + \sin(n))$ does not exist.   You can replace the limit by $\lim\inf$.

Comment: You are right. I corrected the answer.